# Security aspect vs Security goal

Tags: integrity, confidentiality, availability

What is the difference between a security goal and a security aspect ? I know about the three network security goals Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability. But I do not know much about security aspects.

Comment: I would think a security aspect is more narrow by definition. For example using SHA1 vs SHA2-256, aspects can be Key Derivation Function, choosing a mechanism of sharing secrets, etc.

Answer (score 3):

When you look at something from a security perspective, its *security aspects* emerge. That often refers to the security-related principles and concepts which are part of a particular technology. (This technology doesn't have to be about security itself.)

Examples:

> Anonymity is an important security aspect of wireless communications and has continuously attracted significant attention.

[(Source)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sec.78/abstract)

> We know that establishing a person's identity is an important security aspect of government transactions.

[(Source)](http://dominicperrottet.com.au/what-governments-can-learn-from-amazon/)

As opposed to overall *security goals*, security aspects are specific to a product or technology and can't be generalized in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This however does not provide the academic definition of what a security aspect is.

Comment: @sasuke_X220 That's because there is none. A security aspect is nothing more than the "security-related" part about something. It's not a precisely used term.

Comment: I see. Security itself is an aspect from the standpoint of Aspect Oriented Programming for instance.